# Make the order available in checkout pane callback when viewing

Tags: ubercart

I've overridden the payment pane callback in the checkout page (using hook_checkout_pane_alter), and I want to modify the form inputs in the pane based on the order total. However, the order object is empty when the callback is called with the "view" operation parameter.

How do I make the order available in the callback function?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use an order pane instead.